# Apply prop.test to each row in a dataframe

Tags: r

Beginner here: I'm trying to apply the prop.test function in r to each row of a dataframe. If I have a large table, how can I apply the function row-wise without referencing each element? I tried the broom::tidy function but this provides only the proportion and I need the 95% confidence intervals.

```
> a<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(5,6,7,8))
> z=rowSums(a)
> b<-cbind(a,z)
> b
  x y  z
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
4 4 8 12

# inefficient code:
prop.test(b[1,1],b[1,3])
prop.test(b[2,1],b[2,3])
prop.test(b[3,1],b[3,3])
prop.test(b[4,1],b[4,3])

# doesn't provide 95% confidence intervals
broom::tidy(prop.test(b$x, b$z))
```

Answer (score 2):

We may need `rowwise` operation instead of applying `prop.test` on the entire columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
b %>%
     rowwise %>%
      summarise(out = list(prop.test(x, z) %>%
             tidy)) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      unnest(cols = c(out))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                                               alternative
     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                                <chr>      
1    0.167      1.5    0.221         1  0.00876     0.635 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided  
2    0.25       1.12   0.289         1  0.0445      0.644 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided  
3    0.3        0.9    0.343         1  0.0809      0.646 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided  
4    0.333      0.75   0.386         1  0.113       0.646 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided
```

---

Or in `base R`, it would be `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(\(x, y) tidy(prop.test(x, y)), b$x, b$z))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                                               alternative
     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                                <chr>      
1    0.167      1.5    0.221         1  0.00876     0.635 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided  
2    0.25       1.12   0.289         1  0.0445      0.644 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided  
3    0.3        0.9    0.343         1  0.0809      0.646 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided  
4    0.333      0.75   0.386         1  0.113       0.646 1-sample proportions test with continuity correction two.sided
```

Comment: Latest version of one of these packages gives a warning to explicitly specify the col name(s) being unnested as such - ```%>%
      unnest(cols = c(out))``

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apply` to apply a function to each row of a data frame:

```
apply(b, 1, function(df) prop.test(df[1], df[3]))
```

This returns a list:

```
l <- apply(b, 1, function(df) prop.test(df[1], df[3]))
typeof(l)
[1] "list"
```

So you could access these by list indices, e.g. `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, etc. You could also use `unlist(l)` to unwrap the list, but this may not give results that are as easy to access.

You could also apply by column label:

```
apply(b, 1, function(df) prop.test(df['x'], df['z']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with a simple function:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  for (i in c(1:nrow(x))) {
    print(prop.test(b[i,1],b[i,3]))
  }
}

myFun(b)
```

Comment: In R, using a `for` loop is usually the slowest way to run a function on each row. Vectorized approaches like `apply` etc. are better for scalability.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds of course You are right, in general all types of loops execute in a similar time and are not very efficient for large inputs, however they give the correct solution and allow beginners to better understand how the function works.

Comment: I'd suggest reading Patrick Burns' *R Inferno* about loops and vectorization: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf